# How to delete local database object which are not available on server using RestKit for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, restkit-0.20

Hello I have used RestKit for my iPhone application. I fetched the result from server and save into local database. But If we delete the few record from server which are available into my local database. So how I can delete those data entry using RestKit. Have any in build method into RestKit, using that we can easily handle this scenario.

Comment: For this you have to write notification kind of thing. If something deleted from server get newer data from server and update it accordingly.

Comment: what are u using for syncing operation? I would suggest performs sync operation within local database & server. There are two types of sync operation 1. Optimistic 2. Pessimistic. You can go for Optimistic by using time stamp in your server database & local database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the addFetchRequestBlock to give a fetch request with the predicate, by which you can avoid saving unwanted objects from responses.

So, here in the addFetchRequestBlock, you can give the predicate without any condition for the corresponding URL. So it will delete all objects and will insert new objects.

Reference : http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RestKit/0.24.0/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html